# PagerTabStrip title background color

Tags: android, colors, background

I changed the background color in PagerTabStrip, but the tabs titles have a white background

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#c9c9c9"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    />
```

where do I change it?

Comment: Did you have any luck fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a resource file if it does not exist (for colors) at res/values/colors.xml with a color having the value you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <color name="tabstrip_bg">#ff6d9850</color>
</resources>
```

In your layout file (holding respective ViewPager and TabStrip) modify the android:background parameter that refers to above color, as shown below.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager_charts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/tabstrip_bg" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting this **XML** code:

`android:textColor="#<COLOR-CODE>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in code with [PagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(boolean drawFull)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html#setDrawFullUnderline%28boolean%29).

Here's a post on styling the PagerTabStrip.

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1378

**Update:**
Looking at the source for PagerTabStrip, it doesn't appear this is possible. The onDraw() method calls to the super class, which draws the text, then PagerTabStrip draws the indicator at the bottom of the view.  To change the background of the text that is currently selected you would need to draw the indicator at full height before the text was drawn.

This would require a custom class, probably using the code from PagerTabStrip and it's super class, and customizing the onDraw method for your needs.

The code for onDraw() from PagerTabStrip is below.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    final int height = getHeight();
    final int bottom = height;
    final int left = mCurrText.getLeft() - mTabPadding;
    final int right = mCurrText.getRight() + mTabPadding;
    final int top = bottom - mIndicatorHeight;

    mTabPaint.setColor(mTabAlpha << 24 | (mIndicatorColor & 0xFFFFFF));
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mTabPaint);

    if (mDrawFullUnderline) {
        mTabPaint.setColor(0xFF << 24 | (mIndicatorColor & 0xFFFFFF));
        canvas.drawRect(getPaddingLeft(), height - mFullUnderlineHeight,
                getWidth() - getPaddingRight(), height, mTabPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: tab indicator color only changes the line under the title, not the background of the title

Comment: I updated the answer, I think setDrawFullUnderline(true) will do what you want.

Answer (score -4):

just set the ImageButton background to black in pager tab strip java class.

Comment: search it in pagertabstrip class